# C server weird behavior

Tags: c, sockets, unix

So, I have this piece of code, which will just read the message from the client and reply with a "yup"

```
while(strcmp(buffer, "QUIT") != 0){ 
    bzero(buffer, 255); //cleans the read buffer

    /*this reads the aux (request) from the client*/
    recv(newsockfd, buffer, 255, 0);

    if(strlen(buffer))
        printf("Thread %d: %s\n", thread_no, buffer);
    fflush(stdout);

    write(newsockfd, "yup\n", 4);
}
```

The problem is that at the very first reading everything goes ok, but all other readings are messed up, if I send the message "guitar", for example, it gets the 'g', loops and then it gets the "uitar", sending aother "yup".

I have no clue what's happening.

Comment: What in your code do you think prevents this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Long story short: TCP isn't a message orientated protocol, it's a stream orientated protocol. Messages might be fragmented or merged together, and your application has to deal with that (the only guarantee is that you'll receive the data in the same *order* you sent it in).

Comment: Or, to put it as simply as possible, you forgot to design and implement a protocol that has the semantics you need.

Answer (score 0):

`recv()` reads as many data as are available currently. You should read until you hit EOF, an error or a newline. Only if you have that newline, you have a complete line which you then compare with "QUIT", and which youi acknowledge with "Yup."

Answer (score 0):

Three other bugs in the code snippit above.

1) Not checking the return value from recv(). The socket could have been closed gracefully (return value == 0), suffered an error (return value == -1), etc... More importantly, there's not to suggest that you will receive all 4 bytes of the "QUIT" message that was sent by a remote send call.  You may only receive "Q".

2) If recv() were to receive 255 characters (none of which being a null char), then the subsequent strlen() will read into invalid memory and possibly crash.

3) Not checking the return value of the write call.